# How to give referrer url for localhost in google map api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map geocode api for getting city,country,and state from zip code. I have restricted the API key to only respond to requests from allowed URLs.

It works fine except when I try to give referrer url for localhost it doesn't work. 
I am getting error "**RefererNotAllowedMapError**";

I don't understand how to give url for edit because every time the url of edit changes. Please share solutions if there is a way to allow the API to be accessed from localhost.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I had that problem today, just typed "localhost" on the credentials part and it worked.
[image]

Comment: I don't want to sound lame but I got to ask this. My question: Where did you specify `.syrup.co.uk` in your console or app so this URL is identified by Google. I am using Ionic angular visual studio.
In my dev env I am using `localhost:4000` to make calls to Google map API and it works fine. I have auth url registered as `localhost:4000/#something/googlePlaces`. What should be this URL when I make calls Android app hosted in play store?

Comment: if you already have an api key, and you want this screen, then click on the api name inorder to get to this screen

Comment: I tried to set `http://localhost`, `http://localhost:*/*` and `*localhost*` but any of this worked. Using simple string `localhost` as you suggested WORKED!

Answer (score 10):

Try to create an API key again. I would suggest you to follow [Get a Key/Authentication](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

NOTE:

> Google Maps APIs are available for Android or iOS apps, Web browsers, and via HTTP web services. APIs in each platform require a specific type of key. The Google Maps JavaScript API will only work with a *Browser key*. APIs of the same platform can use the same key.

Also, check [Registering authorized URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls) to validate if you are entering a correct format URL.

For example:

`http://localhost` or `http://localhost:[PORT_NUMBER]`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

`localhost:52200/*` worked for me in July 2019. Didn't need explicit protocol like `http` or `https`.

Comment: Documentation says: "All subpaths of an authorized path are also authorized". So you can use just `localhost:52200`

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

`http://localhost` wasn't enough for me, but adding an asterisk worked: `http://localhost/*`