# Google Maps JS API on localhost: RefererNotAllowedMapError

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

For duplicate-tempted visitors: I'm aware of all similar issues but mine is not solved by them

I'm developing locally a react app and my code looks like:

```
<Script
    url={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY || ""}&libraries=places` }
    onLoad={ this.handleScriptLoad }
/>
```

and my console looks like:
[image: google console]

But I still get:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
>   Your site URL to be authorized: http://localhost:3000/

And I have waited for 2+ hours

Comment: Any luck?  Running into the same issue

Comment: Same problem, except it says `Your site URL to be authorized: https://localhost/`.  Have you had any luck?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same problem but this seemed to work for me:

http://localhost/

Just make sure you click "Save" below

Answer (score 0):

Publish your site for example, yoursite.blacktech.com
Add custom hosts to `/etc/hosts to mask 127.0.0.1` myname.blacktech.id
Add domain referer google cloud console `*.blacktech.com`

Go to this flag `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure Enable` and add `myname.blacktech.id` to the list

Answer (score -6):

not localhost

need your ip

ex) 123.12.1.123:3000

Comment: wait so everytime I move/get a new IP I should change it? But I checked HTTP referrer not IP

Comment: Can not distinguish localhost from Google Maps. You should apply for a floating IP address every time. but It is possible if you own the domain.

Comment: So why do these answers seem to work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006171/how-to-give-referrer-url-for-localhost-in-google-map-api

Comment: sry. I did not know that well. referrens 
Try changing the ' **localhost* * '

Comment: I solved it by adding a list. http://localhost:3000, https://localhost:3000 
I do not know why I need to add https

Comment: Hi , did you have to regenerate the credentials after you added https, I added https and still giving me the same error, Thanks

Comment: That's incorrect. You should provide "http://localhost" in the referer field.